# How to separate msql result into different html columns

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a table:

```
| s_id | s_date     | s_movie               | s_hour | s_price |
|    1 | 2015-11-11 | The lord of the rings |  11:00 |       5 |
|    2 | 2015-11-11 | The lord of the rings |  11:00 |       4 |
|    3 | 2015-11-11 | The lord of the rings |  11:00 |       4 |
|    4 | 2015-11-11 | Harry Potter          |  12:00 |       5 |
|    5 | 2015-11-11 | Harry Potter          |  12:00 |      13 |
|    6 | 2015-11-11 | Harry Potter          |  12:00 |      13 |
|    7 | 2015-11-11 | Harry Potter          |  12:00 |       5 |
```

And result:

```
$result = mysql_query("
    SELECT *
     , count(s_price) as uniq_p 
     , SUM(s_price) as uniq_all 
    from table 
    group 
    by s_movie
     , s_price 
    order 
    by s_movie desc
");
```

HTML table display:

```
+------------+------------+--------+-----+
| Date       | Movie      | Price  | Sum |
+------------+------------+--------+-----+
| 2015-11-11 | The lord.. | 2 x 4  |   8 |
| 2015-11-11 | The lord.. | 1 x 5  |   5 |
| 2015-11-11 | Harry..    | 2 x 5  |  10 |
| 2015-11-11 | Harry..    | 2 x 13 |  26 |
```

How to join results like this?

```
+------------+-------------+---------+---------+-----+    
| Date       | Movie       | Price_1 | Price_2 | Sum |
+------------+-------------+---------+---------+-----+  
| 2015-11-11 | The lord..  |  1 x 5  |  2 x 4  |  13 |
| 2015-11-11 | Harry..     |  2 x 13 |  2 x 5  |  36 |
```

Here is a msql example:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2c0f4/2

Comment: Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: You could use a [cross-tab query](http://evolt.org/node/26896/). Setup a SQLFiddle with the data and we can work on your specific data set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Naturally you can do it all in php and it's probably the best way to go about it.

Now if you still want to do the most of it in the database you can do this

**UPDATED:**

```sql
SELECT s_date, s_movie, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(price_count, ' x ', s_price) ORDER BY s_price DESC) prices, 
       SUM(s_price * price_count) price_sum
  FROM
(
  SELECT s_date, s_movie, s_price, COUNT(*) price_count, SUM(s_price) price_sum
    FROM table1
   GROUP BY s_date, s_movie, s_price
) q
 GROUP BY s_date, s_movie DESC
```

Which will give you the following:

```
+---------------------+-----------------------+--------------+-----------+
| s_date              | s_movie               | prices       | price_sum |
+---------------------+-----------------------+--------------+-----------+
| 2015-11-11 00:00:00 | The lord of the rings | 1 x 5,2 x 4  |        13 |
| 2015-11-11 00:00:00 | Harry Potter          | 2 x 13,2 x 5 |        36 |
+---------------------+-----------------------+--------------+-----------+
```

Here is [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aaf3d4/2) demo

Now you can `explode()` `prices` column value by `,` while you're iterating over the resultset.

Comment: but he wanted a separate select

Comment: Sorry, but there is a little problem. I want always first in **Price_1** to be big price then in **Price_2** - small. Any idea?  [link](http://imgur.com/5wBa4ww)

Comment: @TihomirTodorov See the updated answer. Notice `ORDER BY` used with `GROUP_CONCAT`.

Comment: Thanks, **peterm**. Now everything is perfect!